# If $X$ follows a binomial distribution, then what is $P(1.25<X<1.75)$?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

Do I understand it correctly that $$P(1.25 < X < 1.75) = P (X <1.75) - P(X < 1.25)= P(X \le 1) -P(X \le 1)=0?$$

Another question : Is $$P(0.5 < X <1.5) = P(X =1)?$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cute profile. Consider giving a [check mark](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) to past, present, and future respondents. Also, please try to format your posts. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: awesome, thanks for the tips. just saved it.:D

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  If $X \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n,p)$, then $\Pr[1.25 < X < 1.75] = 0$, because the support of $X$ is on the set $X \in \{0, 1, \ldots, n\}$.  Since there are no integers between $1.25$ and $1.75$, the desired probability is zero.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please confirm whether I was correct or not in the second question. Again, many thinks.

Comment: @YilinWang Yes, your conclusion for your second question is also correct.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to look at it is that the event 
$1.25<X<1.75$ is an empty event since the only possible values of $X$ are integers $k$, $0\leq k\leq n$. Hence
$$P(1.25<X<1.75) = P(\varnothing) = 0.$$

For the second part, notice
$$\{.5<X<1.5\}\iff \{X = 1\}$$
and hence
$$P(.5<X<1.5) = P(X=1).$$